# How to do a pull request from a forked repository

Tags: git, pull-request

I'm a bit new with Git and need some help. I have forked an online respository that I'm using in my own project. Now and then I would like to make some pull requests to the original repo, but as I've made local changes in my fork that I *don't* want in the pull requests, I'm a bit unsure of the process.

Can I create a pull request from a branch made from my local version, and merge that with the upstream? Or would I basically have to check out the original repo, make the changes, and make a pull request from this branch? This meaning, I would effectively do the changes twice – once for my local fork, and once in a branch that I make a pull request from. Is there a way to do the changes once, and apply them both places, even though the fork is ahead of the original repo?

I tried the first version, but I guess that would bring with it other changes from my fork, which I guess makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a remote for `upstream` yet, you can add it using `git remote add upstream <url>`. This way your local repo gets two remotes, origin (fork) and upstream. Use `git fetch upstream` to update the remote branches for `upstream`.

You should now branch out from `upstream/master` (or whatever their default branch is), to get rid of commits in your fork that you don't want in the PR.
You can then use `git cherry-pick` to "transfer" specific commits from one branch to another. Now you can push this branch to origin, and open a PR in upstream.

Make sure to check that you got the correct changes when you're opening the PR

Comment: Ah, thank you! Now I think I get it. I have the upstream remote set already, but was confused as to where to branch out. So if I have a feature branch on my origin I want to make a pull request from, I open a new branch from upstream/master, and cherry pick commits onto that one before pushing it to origin and make the pull request? Last question – their default branch is “develop”, which naturally can be ahead of their master, this would normally be the one to branch off from then?

Comment: Yup! You branch out from the branch that your PR will merge into

Comment: Makes perfect sense, was over thinking it! :) Thank you!